# npm install issue with proxy

Tags: node.js, angular

I have installed NodeJS in my machine and when i try to run the command npm install via the command prompt then the network is blocking to download the node_modules into my machine. So strangely when i use the npm install command, it shows the below message along with some other error messages: npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.0.162:443.

So with this issue i have raised to out network team that i am getting this error then they said they will open this IP for my system and strangely what happened next is when they have opened this particular IP address for my system i got the same error with the IP address got changed to npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.8.162:443.

So what my question is if the command prompt says like this then how can i develop the Angular 4 app in my machine. Is there any solution to overcome this? Can anybody provide any inputs on this issue.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, before execute che install command, have you config npm proxy and  https-proxy environment variables? You can also set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables before execute npm install comand.

Comment: run 
`npm config set proxy http://login:pass@yourproxy:proxyport` and
`npm config set https-proxy http://login:pass@yourproxy:proxyport` and `npm config set strict-ssl false`.

Comment: Above would add .npmrc file in your computers user folder containing proxy bypass info

Comment: Rahul, Great it worked for me! Thanks!!